# KB3023222 update causes problems to the MonthCalendar control

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, monthcalendar

right after I installed the update (KB3023222) I started getting an error whenever I changed the chosen date on a MonthCalendar control in my application, which used to work flawlessly in the past. Has this happened to anybody else? Is there any explanation or workaround?

This is the content of the exception:

"Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object."

And the details:

```
************** Exception Text **************
System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
   at System.Windows.Forms.MonthCalendar.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

I'm using windows 8.1, C# and the latest .NET.

Comment: dotPeek shows that exception can be thrown while handling `WM_DESTROY`, if you aren't in a fully trusted context, and something something with a registry entry named `AllowWindowsFormsReentrantDestroy`

Comment: But the only place Google knows about that is the Reference Source: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/MonthCalendar.cs

Comment: There is no such registry entry. I don't understand the use of this reference. Will you please explain?

Comment: The registry entry most likely puts the behavior back the way it was before the update.  But there is no documentation for it, except the source code (linked above)

Comment: I understand now... thanks for the suggestion! I will try it later and post the results. Is adding this entry a security flaw?

Comment: @Ben Voigt I created a dword "AllowWindowsFormsReentrantDestroy"=1 in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework, restarted and it works! You can post it as a solution if you'd like. Also please clarify this one for me, are there any security risks with this workaround? Thanks a lot!